# pvals.fnc does not work with random intercept and slope. How to get p-values?

Tags: r, p-value

I am doing LMM in lme4, and have installed languageR to run pvas.fnc(), but it does not work with random intercept and slope.

This is the message:

```
Error in pvals.fnc(lmer1) : 
  MCMC sampling is not yet implemented in lme4_0.999375
  for models with random correlation parameters
```

For model with only random intercept, this function works fine. Then what should I do to get the p-values?

Comment: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/lme4/docs/pvalues

Comment: Thanks Roland. I have tried KRmodcomp to get p-values for fixed-effects, but it does not work as two models have the same number of parameters: Error in KRmodcomp.lmerMod(lmer1, lmer2) : Models have either equal fixed mean stucture or are not nested Then I tried deleting one factors so that the number of parameters between two models are unequal, but still get this: Note: method with signature ‘sparseMatrix#ANY’ chosen for function ‘kronecker’, target signature ‘dgCMatrix#ngCMatrix’. "ANY#sparseMatrix" would also be valid F-test with Kenward-Roger approximation; computing time: 25.60 sec. stat

Comment: Have you updated the package?

Comment: can we have a reproducible example, or at least more information?